# Alfresco audit query: fromTime/toTime seem to have no effect

Tags: rest, alfresco, audit

I want to get all audit entries from an Alfresco audit application.

Following the [Alfresco Audit REST API documentation](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/audit-rest-api.html), I wrote this query:

```
curl -u admin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/audit-custom?fromId=1&toId=100000&fromTime=2017-02-19T18:46:09.212+09:00&toTime=2017-02-20T18:46:09.212+09:00&user=admin&forward=true&limit=0&verbose=true"
```

*(Note the `fromTime={2017-02-19T18:46:09.212+09:00}&toTime={2017-02-20T18:46:09.212+09:00}` part)*

**PROBLEM:** This returns the exact same 90 results as the request without the fromTime and toTime parameters. By the way, I installed Alfresco on 2017-02-21 so the query above should actually return zero results.

- Same problem with `{` and `}` characters around the dates
- Same problem with simpler dates like `fromTime={2017-02-19}&toTime={2017-02-20}`
- Same problem without the extra parameters

How to use correctly the `fromTime` and `toTime` parameters?

Answer (score 2):

It is not obvious in the documentation, but `fromTime` and `longTime` must be entered as [long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) values.

Here is the relevant Alfresco source code:

```
public static final String PARAM_FROM_TIME = "fromTime";

protected Long getParamFromTime(WebScriptRequest req)
{
    String paramStr = req.getParameter(PARAM_FROM_TIME);
    try
    {
        return Long.parseLong(paramStr);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return DEFAULT_TO_TIME;
    }
}
```

As you can see, format problems are quietly dropped, and default values used instead, which is what is happening with the requests included in the question above.

With long values, a valid request could be:

```
curl -u admin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/audit-custom?fromTime=1485152993728&toTime=1485239393728&verbose=true"
```

*(Note the `fromTime=1485152993728&toTime=1485239393728` part)*

Here is a convenient Java snippet to convert dates to long values when performing tests:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastMonth = now - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30); 
        long lastMonthPlusOne = now - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(29);

        System.out.println("Now:" + now);
        System.out.println("Last month:" + lastMonth);
        System.out.println("Last month plus one day:" + lastMonthPlusOne);
    }
}
```